# How to use inner class variable in whole class

Tags: android, loopj

I have a method like this to get firstname from webservices using loopj.

```
private void getfirstName() {
  List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
    headers.add(new BasicHeader("Accept", "application/json"));

  RestClient.getShiftCodes(MainActivity.this, "RestService/First_Name", headers.toArray(new Header[headers.size()]),
            null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
  ArrayList<String> firstNameArray = new ArrayList<String>();   
  for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
  try {
         JSONObject c = response.getJSONObject(i);
         String  first_NameArray = c.getString("firstName");
         firstNameArray.add(first_NameArray); 
       } 
       catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   String first_Name= firstNameArray.get(0);
  }
 });

}
```

If I want to use the first_name string value in other methods, I get this error

```
Cannot refer to a non-final variable first_name inside an inner class defined in a different method
```

Even if I change it to final I cannot use it. How can I use it in the whole class.

Comment: Please read about scope and lifetime of a variable. Meanwhile I will post a good answer for you.

Comment: you are missing `{` at the end of `public void onSuccess()`

Comment: This not useful comment and not related to the question. Somehow it was made a mistake of content format by him !

Comment: @MohammedAtif Okay. Yes Please post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot be able to get the reference of inner class variable directly instead declare in outer class and assign the value in inner class. Then You can access the variable from any of the classes.

Comment: Actually i tried that, but i get null value. What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Do not use the variable before assigning. Assign the value and after your inner class task is done. Then use the variable. i:e in OnComplete Listner.

Comment: Okay i will check again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. it worked

Answer (score 1):

```
String first_Name
```

Declare out side function

Comment: Actually i tried that, but i get null value. What i am doing wrong ? any suggestion please

Comment: Inside function it's null ?

Comment: Inside the same method i get the value. In other methods its null.that is my problem. i am not able to use it.

Comment: where the other methods are ? is it in same class ? can you post your class ?

Comment: Yes other methods in same class. Its lengthy class i cant post here :(

Comment: use can use http://paste.ofcode.org/ to post your class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123768/discussion-between-user3785322-and-pcpriyanka).